# Need help creating a html table in Moodle using the table library. SQL WORKS. I need help to convert SQL to API format

Tags: php, html, sql, api, moodle

This is a working example of SQL:
=========== SQL ===========

```
-- $fields
SELECT recent_entry.contact_id, to_timestamp(recent_entry.lastmodified), contact.caseid, contact.client_first_name, contact.client_last_name

-- $from
FROM (
  -- nested table
  SELECT contact_id, max(lastmodified) as lastmodified
  FROM (
    -- most nested TABLE
    SELECT contact.id as contact_id, contact.timemodified lastmodified
      FROM mdl_block_caseman_contact contact
     WHERE to_timestamp(contact.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
    UNION
    SELECT back.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, back.timemodified lastmodified
      FROM mdl_block_caseman_back back
     WHERE to_timestamp(back.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
    UNION
    SELECT engagement.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, max(engagement.timemodified) lastmodified
      FROM mdl_block_caseman_engagements engagement
     WHERE to_timestamp(engagement.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
    GROUP BY engagement.caseman_contact_id
    UNION
    SELECT app.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, max(app.timemodified) lastmodified
      FROM mdl_block_caseman_apps app
     WHERE to_timestamp(app.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
    GROUP BY app.caseman_contact_id
  ) recent_entries
  GROUP BY contact_id
) recent_entry
INNER JOIN mdl_block_caseman_contact contact ON contact.id = recent_entry.contact_id
 
-- $where
ORDER BY recent_entry.lastmodified DESC
;
```

===========================

I need some assistance in converting this to the Moodle API formate. I have tried the following code however, I receive an error.

```
//https://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/tablelib.php
require "../../config.php";
require "$CFG->libdir/tablelib.php";
require "./classes/dashboard_table.php";
//require "./classes/dashboard_table2.php";
//require "./classes/dashboard_table3.php";
//require "./classes/dashboard_table4.php";

$context = context_system::instance();
$PAGE->set_context($context);
$PAGE->set_url('/blocks/caseman/dashboard.php');
$PAGE->set_pagelayout("standard");

global $USER, $DB;

require_login();
//require_capability("block/caseman:enter_cm", $context);

$download = optional_param('download', '', PARAM_ALPHA);

$table = new dashboard_table('uniqueid');
$table->is_downloading($download, 'dashboard', 'dashboarding123');
//https://www.moodlewiki.com/books/development/page/move-the-download-options-below-a-table
//display download button at the bottom of table
$table->show_download_buttons_at(array(TABLE_P_BOTTOM));
if (!$table->is_downloading()) {
    // Only print headers if not asked to download data.
    // Print the page header.
    $PAGE->set_title(get_string('tsm_cms_dashboard', 'block_caseman'));
    $PAGE->set_heading(get_string('dashboard_heading', 'block_caseman'));
    $PAGE->navbar->add(get_string("page_navbar_cm_dashboard", "block_caseman"), 
            new moodle_url('/blocks/caseman/dashboard.php'));
    
    echo $OUTPUT->header();
}


$fields = "SELECT recent_entry.contact_id, to_timestamp(recent_entry.lastmodified), contact.caseid, contact.client_first_name, contact.client_last_name";


 $from = "FROM (
  SELECT contact_id, max(lastmodified) as lastmodified
  FROM (
    SELECT contact.id as contact_id, contact.timemodified lastmodified
      FROM {block_caseman_contact contact}
     WHERE to_timestamp(contact.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
    UNION
    SELECT back.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, back.timemodified lastmodified
      FROM mdl_block_caseman_back back
     WHERE to_timestamp(back.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
    UNION
    SELECT engagement.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, max(engagement.timemodified) lastmodified
      FROM mdl_block_caseman_engagements engagement
     WHERE to_timestamp(engagement.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
    GROUP BY engagement.caseman_contact_id
    UNION
    SELECT app.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, max(app.timemodified) lastmodified
      FROM mdl_block_caseman_apps app
     WHERE to_timestamp(app.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
    GROUP BY app.caseman_contact_id
  ) recent_entries
  GROUP BY contact_id
) recent_entry
INNER JOIN {block_caseman_contact} contact ON contact.id = recent_entry.contact_id";

 
 $where = "ORDER BY recent_entry.lastmodified DESC";






$table->set_sql($fields, $from, $where);


//$table->set_sql($fields, $from, $where, $params);
$table->define_baseurl("$CFG->wwwroot/dashboard.php");


$table->out(10, true);

if (!$table->is_downloading()) {
    echo $OUTPUT->footer();
}
```

The error that I get is here:
Error reading from database

More information about this error

×Debug info: ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"

```
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FROM (
^
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FROM (
SELECT contact_id, max(lastmodified) as lastmodified
FROM (
SELECT contact.id as contact_id, contact.timemodified lastmodified
FROM {block_caseman_contact contact}
WHERE to_timestamp(contact.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
UNION
SELECT back.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, back.timemodified lastmodified
FROM mdl_block_caseman_back back
WHERE to_timestamp(back.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
UNION
SELECT engagement.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, max(engagement.timemodified) lastmodified
FROM mdl_block_caseman_engagements engagement
WHERE to_timestamp(engagement.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
GROUP BY engagement.caseman_contact_id
UNION
SELECT app.caseman_contact_id as contact_id, max(app.timemodified) lastmodified
FROM mdl_block_caseman_apps app
WHERE to_timestamp(app.timemodified) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
GROUP BY app.caseman_contact_id
) recent_entries
GROUP BY contact_id
) recent_entry
INNER JOIN mdl_block_caseman_contact contact ON contact.id = recent_entry.contact_id WHERE ORDER BY recent_entry.lastmodified DESC
[array (
)]
```

Error code: dmlreadexception
×Stack trace:

```
line 486 of \lib\dml\moodle_database.php: dml_read_exception thrown
line 329 of \lib\dml\pgsql_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
line 920 of \lib\dml\pgsql_native_moodle_database.php: call to pgsql_native_moodle_database->query_end()
line 1624 of \lib\dml\moodle_database.php: call to pgsql_native_moodle_database->get_records_sql()
line 1697 of \lib\dml\moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->get_record_sql()
line 1907 of \lib\dml\moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->get_field_sql()
line 1964 of \lib\tablelib.php: call to moodle_database->count_records_sql()
line 2019 of \lib\tablelib.php: call to table_sql->query_db()
line 114 of \blocks\caseman\dashboard.php: call to table_sql->out()
```

Comment: The error shows the query as: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FROM`. The `FROM` keyword is written twice, the other most likely automatically added by the `set_sql` function. My bet is that the variables you pass into that function aren't supposed to contain keywords. Try removing them from your strings and see if it helps.

Comment: [Here's the source code](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/tablelib.php#L1956) of the function you're using. Read its comments and adjust your variables accordingly.